# Fatal Python error stemming from tensorflow/transformers packages

Tags: python, tensorflow, fatal-error

I've been getting a Fatal Python error: Illegal instruction. The error seems to stem from tensorflow and transformers.py.
I have python 3.9, tensorflow 2.14.0 and transformers 4.33.2. My operating system is Mac.

The error message is long but here are a few lines:

```
`Fatal Python error: Illegal instruction.

Main thread:
Current thread 0x0000000202868280 (most recent call first):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1173 in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 565 in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007 in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1058 in _handle_fromlist
(Then it leads to specific files that produce these messages such as transformers/image_transforms.py)`
```

I tried `sys.settrace` and increasing the recurson limit, e.g. sys.setrecursionlimit(100000)
Still crashing and restarting my kernel.

Comment: Is this an M1 Mac? If so, you are using Intel libraries and Rosetta emulation does not support all instructions used by some libraries. You need to install native arm64 versions of all libraries.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy it's an M2 Mac (Apple M2 Pro)

Comment: The same applies then.